# Duplicate scrape targets on different ports

Tags: prometheus

I'm using a scrape config that is very similar to the suggested ones in the examples. For some reason I have duplicate scrape targets. I'd like to know why this is the case

My scrape config:

```
  - job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'
    kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: pod
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [ __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape ]
        action: keep
        regex: true
      - source_labels: [ __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path ]
        action: replace
        target_label: __metrics_path__
        regex: (.+)
      - source_labels: [ __address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port ]
        action: replace
        regex: (.+):(?:\d+);(\d+)
        replacement: ${1}:${2}
        target_label: __address__
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
      - action: labeldrop
        regex: statefulset_kubernetes_io_pod_name # This is duplicate because we already have the pod_name
      - source_labels: [ __meta_kubernetes_namespace ]
        action: replace
        target_label: kubernetes_namespace
      - source_labels: [ __meta_kubernetes_pod_name ]
        action: replace
        target_label: kubernetes_pod_name
```

Accordingly I set the annotations on the to be scraped pods:

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    checksum/config: "8755a7a06e8302a6861c536738da919828761d7c6a794b2c52c920b4ddae163e"
    cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: "172.22.130.165/32"
    kubernetes.io/psp: "prometheus"
    prometheus.io/path: "/metrics"
    prometheus.io/port: "9090"
    prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
```

Now for some reason all of these targets appear twice (under different ports) in the scrape targets as shown in the Prometheus UI:

[image: Prometheus scrape targets]

Why is this the case? Why does it appear under port 80? The target with port `9090` shows that the relabel config where it reads the port from the annotation works.

Additional information:

- the prometheus pod is part of a stateful set
- it defines just one (unnamed) port 9090
- it has an init container that doesn't expose a port
- the screenshot oviously only shows scrape targets from the `kubernetes-pods` job
- this is just prometheus (v2.22.0) and is not managed by the prometheus operator

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the service discovery page of these two targets?

Comment: @weibeld I can provide them, unfortunately due to the sheer amount of labels it's hard to get them onto one picture. Are you looking for something particular? The pod `prometheus-0` appears twice in the service discovery. Once with instance = "ip:80" and the second with instance = "ip:9090"

Comment: See possible solution in answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`pod`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#pod) service discovery role of Prometheus creates a target for each container of your Pod, including init containers. You have an init container in your Pod, so this results in two targets.

If a container does not declare a port (like your init container), then a port-free target is created. That means, the regex in your `replace` rule that sets `__address__` does not match and Prometheus then uses port 80 by default for this target.

To drop the init container target, try adding the following rule:

```yaml
- source_labels: [ __meta_kubernetes_pod_container_init ]
  regex: true
  action: drop
```

Comment: THanks for your answer, can you further clarify why this relabel item does not work? It does not use a container's port but it rather uses the `__address__` label and uses the `prometheus.io/port` annotation (which is at the pod level). Therefore I do not understand why this does not work for writing the new `__address__`?

Comment: What is the value of the `__address__` label of the two targets before relabelling?

Comment: Oh now I see what you mean. It is the IP address without a port and thus the regex group doesn't match this string! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's what I was supposing because you have a hardcoded `:` in the regex.

Comment: I have been having a similar problem, and this solved it perfectly. Thank you!